# Extracting a large blob from SQL Server to a file takes a very long time in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, blob, bcp

I've been researching a way to automate extraction of blob columns to files, and this [blog](https://sqlrambling.net/2020/04/04/saving-and-extracting-blob-data-basic-examples/) details a few ways to do it.

Via BCP, larger files extract from my database very quickly.  I'm able to extract a 2 gigabyte file in under 20 seconds.  Here's the sample command line I used, based on the examples in the blog:

```
BCP "SELECT PictureData FROM BLOB_Test.dbo.PicturesTest " QUERYOUT C:\BLOBTest\BlobOut\WC.jpg -T -f "C:\BLOBTest\FormatFile\BLOB.fmt" -S <ServerName>\<InstanceName>
```

As an aside, I had to learn about applying a format file to prevent a prefix string from being inserted into the file.  This format file must be in BCP's older format, because the newer XML version of the format file has a schema entry for "PREFIX_LENGTH" that prevents a 0 value.

I would rather use PowerShell to extract the blobs, but the following code based on a [TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/890.export-sql-server-blob-data-with-powershell.aspx) takes about two days to process instead of BCP's 20 seconds for the same 2 gig blob.

```
## https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/890.export-sql-server-blob-data-with-powershell.aspx
## Export of "larger" SQL Server blob to file with GetBytes-Stream

# Configuration data
   $Server     = ".\<Instance>";         # SQL Server Instance
   $Database   = "Blob_Test";            # Name of database
   $Dest       = "C:\BLOBTest\BLOBOut\"; # Path to export to
   $bufferSize = 8192;                   # Stream buffer size in bytes

# Select-Statement for name & blob with filter
   $Sql = "Select 
              [PictureName],
              [PictureData]
           From 
              dbo.PicturesTest";

# Open ADO.NET Connection
   $con = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
   $con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;" +
                           "Integrated Security=True;" +
                           "Initial Catalog=$Database";
   $con.Open();

# New Command and Reader
   $cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $Sql, $con;
   $rd  = $cmd.ExecuteReader();

# Create a byte array for the stream
   $out = [array]::CreateInstance('Byte', $bufferSize)

# Loop through records
   While ($rd.Read()) {
      Write-Output ("Exporting: {0}" -f $rd.GetString(0));
      
      # New BinaryWriter
         $fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($Dest + $rd.GetString(0)), Create, Write;
         $bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter $fs;
      
         $start = 0;

      # Read first byte stream
         $received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1);
      
      While ($received -gt 0) {
         $bw.Write($out, 0, $received);
         $bw.Flush();
         $start += $received;
         
         # Read next byte stream
            $received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1);
      }
      
      $bw.Close();
      $fs.Close();
   }

# Closing & disposing all objects
   $fs.Dispose();
   $rd.Close();
   $cmd.Dispose();
   $con.Close();

Write-Output ("Finished");
```

It does eventually finish, but I don't know why the script takes so long to complete.

Does anyone have an idea why the PowerShell script is being neutered?

Comment: You don't need the BinaryWriter at all. That class is **only** meant to write primitive types in a .NET-specific format. You can use `DbDataReader.GetStream` to get a stream to the binary data and `Stream.CopyTo` to copy from that stream to the file stream, in just two lines, eg :`$dbFs=$rd.GetStream(1); $dbFs.CopyTo($fs);`

Comment: Even if you wanted to work with bytes, you can use `Stream.Write` to write a byte array to a stream. You don't need the BinaryWriter

Comment: Side note the disposing should be in a `try/finally` so that it will always execute even if there is an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the BinaryWriter at all. That class is *only* meant to write primitive types like integers, doubles, strings etc in a .NET-specific format. It's rarely used.

If you want to write bytes to a file all you need is to use [Stream.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.write?view=net-5.0) :

```
$fs.Write $received
```

A better idea that can eliminate almost all the code is to use [DbDataReader.GetStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getstream?view=net-5.0) instead of `GetBytes` to read the BLOB as a stream. After that you can use [Stream.CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=net-5.0) to write the stream's contents to another stream:

```
$dbFs=$rd.GetStream(1); 
$dbFs.CopyTo($fs);
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is going to save me months.  It's really fast.  I'm surprised there aren't other prominent examples using the stream technique.  Just curious, any thoughts as to why the binary writer is so sluggish?

Answer (score 0):

This script from 2010 is still valid and works blazingly fast.

```
$server = ".";
$database = "YourDatab";
$query = "SELECT FileContent,FileName FROM dbo.FileUploads";
$dirPath = "C:\Data\"
 
$connection=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
$connection.ConnectionString="Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True" -f $server,$database
$command=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query,$connection)
$command.CommandTimeout=120
$connection.Open()
$reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
while ($reader.Read())
{
    $sqlBytes = $reader.GetSqlBytes(0)
    $filepath = "$dirPath{0}" -f $reader.GetValue(1)
    $buffer = new-object byte[] -ArgumentList $reader.GetBytes(0,0,$null,0,$sqlBytes.Length)
    $reader.GetBytes(0,0,$buffer,0,$buffer.Length)
    $fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream($filePath,[System.IO.FileMode]'Create',[System.IO.FileAccess]'Write')
    $fs.Write($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
    $fs.Close()
}
$reader.Close()
$connection.Close()
```

Source: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/t-sql-tuesday-006-blobs-filestream-and-powershell